# Search through a concatenated dataframe for exact match and then pull minimum date

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, data-science

So I am new to pandas and am punching above my weight here. I have two csv files: one is a list of authors I am interested in (data frame 1) and the second file is a total list of authors for the publishing company and their publication date (data frame 2).

I need to use data frame 1 to see if there is an exact name match in data frame 2. If there is a match (there can be more than 1 match) I want to pull the minimum date. Ex:) For Jake Smith in df 1 there may be 2 matches in df 2 and i want to add the oldest publication date to data frame 1.

df

`first name|last name |`

df 2

`first name|last name| publication date`

desired

if author is in df1 then add the lowest publication date to df1

So heres what I did. I created the data frames from the csv files and concatenated all the author files to create df2. I then did an inner join on first and last name because I thought that would be the best way to name match. I keep getting an error. And then I used a group by to try and get the minimum date.

```
import pandas as pd

files_path= 'C:'
df_1 = pd.read_csv( files_path + '/author_desired.csv', sep="|")

df_merged= pd.read_csv(files_path +'/master_list.csv', sep="|")

df_final= pd.join(df_1, df_merged, on= ['LAST_NAME' , 'FIRST_NAME'], how='inner')

df_final.groupby(['FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME']).max()['FIRST_PUB_DATE']

df_final.to_csv(files_path + "/merged_file.csv")
```

PLEASE HELP

Comment: Could you please add the error your getting? And what is the format of publication date?

Comment: Could you please add a sample of your dataframe? or link to it?

Comment: im getting a key error on 'LAST_NAME' even though it is a column

Comment: df1: Jake|Smith|NYC, Jamie|Joe|London

Comment: df2: Jake|Smith|2015, Jake|Smith|2014, Judy|James|2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lis1=[{'FIRST_NAME':'James','Last_Name':'Cameran','City':'NYC'},{'FIRST_NAME':'Samuel','Last_Name':'Smith','City':'London'},{'FIRST_NAME':'Kane','Last_Name':'Win','City':'NYC'}]
lis2=[{'FIRST_NAME':'James','Last_Name':'Cameran','Pub. Year':2011},{'FIRST_NAME':'Kane','Last_Name':'Win','Pub. Year':2010},{'FIRST_NAME':'James','Last_Name':'Cameran','Pub. Year':2018},{'FIRST_NAME':'Kane','Last_Name':'Win','Pub. Year':2014}]
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame(lis1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(lis2)

print(df1)
print(df2)

df1['Full_Name']=df1.FIRST_NAME+" "+df1.Last_Name
df2['Full_Name']=df2.FIRST_NAME+" "+df2.Last_Name

merged=pd.merge(df1,df2)[['Full_Name','Pub. Year']]

df1['Pub. Year']=[merged[merged.Full_Name==fullname]['Pub. Year'].min() for fullname in df1.Full_Name]
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
     City FIRST_NAME Last_Name
0     NYC      James   Cameran
1  London     Samuel     Smith
2     NYC       Kane       Win

     FIRST_NAME Last_Name  Pub. Year
0      James   Cameran       2011
1       Kane       Win       2010
2      James   Cameran       2018
3       Kane       Win       2014

     City FIRST_NAME Last_Name      Full_Name  Pub. Year
0     NYC      James   Cameran  James Cameran     2011.0
1  London     Samuel     Smith   Samuel Smith        NaN
2     NYC       Kane       Win       Kane Win     2010.0
```